# Execute half of the %post section of a kickstart in a nochroot environment and the other half in a chroot environment

Tags: redhat, chroot, kickstart

I am trying to execute a script that performs certain security configurations on my  recently installed system. Much of the script refers to files starting with `/` as the base directory which presents a problem as copying the script from my `isolinux` directory requires a nochroot environment where the base directory is `/mnt/sysimage/`. So, is it possible to copy the script over to the correct directory in the nochroot environment, but then once its there switch back to a chroot environment?

For reference, here is what the kickstart's %post section roughly looks like:

```
%post --nochroot --logfile=/mnt/sysimage/root/ks-post.log
cp /run/install/repo/<script.sh> /mnt/sysimage/root/
---> Here is where I want to switch back to a chroot environment
sh /root/script.sh
%end
```

Note that I changed the last line from what it currently is, `sh /mnt/sysimage/root/script.sh`, to reflect the way I want my `%post` section to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%post --nochroot --logfile=/mnt/sysimage/root/ks-post.log
cp /run/install/repo/script.sh /mnt/sysimage/root/
chroot /mnt/sysimage/ /bin/sh /root/script.sh
%end
```